# child of constraint only from child direction, fixed pivot point on parent side

Tags: armature, parent, bone.constraints

I would like to control the position of one bonetail (Bone.003) with two boneheads (Bone.007 & Bone.005).
If I am not mistaken, this is possible trough parenting 003 & 007 and using the child of constraint for bone 005.
[image]

My problem is, that during the animation, I would like to rotate Bone.001 around global Z while the head of Bone.001 stays fixed. Also Bone.003 should stay fixed at its tail.
The motion should then look like this:
[image]
At the same time, it should be possible to control the position of the node between Bone.003, 005 & 007 through the motion of Bone.007 or Bone.005.
So I would like the node only to be able to be moved by the children (Bone.007 & Bone.005) but not by the parent (Bone.003).

The bones marked in red should thus be movable "by hand" while they should stay fixed in place as pivot point if the Bone.003 moves:
[image]

[image]

Comment: You said, "So I would like the node only to be able to be moved by the children but not by the parent (*Bone.007*)." I think you mean *Bone.003*. Can you confirm?

Comment: @MrA you are totally right, I've corrected the question :)

Comment: I think the issue here is you want *Bone.005* to be able to move the node (*Bone.007* and *Bone.003*). At the same time, you want *Bone.007* to be able to move the node (*Bone.005* and *Bone.003*). You want a system that switches the parenting hierarchy based on which bone is being manipulated. I suggest to simplify the problem by introducing one bone that is responsible for moving the node. It will be the parent of *Bone.005* and *Bone.007*, and the IK target for *Bone.003*. However, this would mean that you wouldn't animate *Bone.005* and *Bone.007* anymore. Empty.017 can fill that role.

Comment: yes this solved the issue, thanks a lot!
(btw. I'm new to this forum ... do I have to mark it as solved?)

Comment: You're welcome! I posted my comment as an answer. You can now accept it by clicking the check mark. For more information, you can check [this page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is you want *Bone.005* to be able to move the node (*Bone.007* and *Bone.003*). At the same time, you want *Bone.007* to be able to move the node (*Bone.005* and *Bone.003*). You want a system that switches the parenting hierarchy based on which bone is being manipulated. I suggest to simplify the problem by introducing one bone that is responsible for moving the node. It will be the parent of *Bone.005* and *Bone.007*, and the IK target for *Bone.003*. However, this would mean that you wouldn't animate *Bone.005* nor *Bone.007* anymore. *Empty.017* can fill that role.